# sql compare flight number and day of week combo

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have a problem where I have a table with a lot of flight data, including flight number and day_of_week in 2 separate columns.  I have to send both of them to a separate table (were normalizing it out of a single 54 column table), and the problem states that if a flight flies every day, replace day of week value with 8, otherwise send the data from day_of_week column.  Im thinking of trying to compare the flight_num to a concatenation of flight_num & day_of_week for every day of the week (1-7), but Im not sure how to go about performing this.  Any suggestions?

Comment: please show what did you try about this subject so far.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Edit your Q to show sample inputs/outputs and code. Requests for 
tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the big flight table is "flights_table" and the destination is "new_flights_table"

I'd do it simply using count in two passes :

pass 1 : non regular flights :

```
insert into new_flights_table  
select f1.flightnum,f1.flightday 
    from flights_table f1,
         (select distinct flightnum 
            from flight_table
           group by flightnum
           having count(*)<7) f2 
  where f2.flightnum=f1.flightnum
```

pass2 : the daily flights

```
insert into new_flights_table 
   select  flightnum,8 
            from flight_table
           group by flightnum
           having count(*)=7
```